# Writing a *.d.ts file with exposed default constructor

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a JS library, that I need to import the following way:

```
import * as MyLib from 'my-lib'

//const MyLib=require('my-lib') works too

function run() {
   const a = new MyLib();
}
```

Trying to import it as below doesn't work:

```
import MyLib from 'my-lib'
```

I need to write a *.d.ts file to express that library. Help please...

So far got to here:

```
declare module "my-lib" {
  export default class MyLib {
  }
}
```

But have no idea how to take if from here...

Comment: `import * as MyLib from 'my-lib'` is not `import MyLib from 'my-lib'`

Comment: IIRC that's `exports = MyLib`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the comment from @dimava helped a lot, got me on the right track. Solution:

```
declare module "my-lib" {
  export class MyLib {
  }

  export=MyLib
}
```